# sort objects in doubly linked list

Tags: c++, list, data-structures, linked-list

i am trying to sort a doubly linked list which contain set of objects have name and id attribute and i want to sort it with the id 
i have two classes one for Employee and the other is LinkedList 
this is function sort and function swap from LinkedList class
the problem is this sort function is not sorting, it show unmeaning data after sorting

```
void LinkedList::Sort()
{
    Employee *tempFirst,*tempSeconed;
    tempFirst=pStart;
    tempSeconed = pStart->pNext;

    while(tempSeconed!=NULL && tempFirst->getId()<tempSeconed->getId())
    {
        tempFirst= tempFirst->pNext;
        tempSeconed= tempSeconed->pNext;

    }

    swap(tempFirst,tempSeconed);

}
void LinkedList::swap(Employee *x , Employee *y)
{
    Employee *temp;
    temp->setName(x->getName());
    temp->setId(x->getId());

    x->setName(y->getName());
    x->setId(y->getId());

    y->setName(temp->getName());
    y->setId(temp->getId());
}
```

this is class employee

```
class Employee
{
    private:
        int id;
        char* name;


    public:
        Employee *pNext;
        Employee *pPrevious;
        void printEmployee();

        void setId(int id);
        int getId();

        void setName(char* name);
        char* getName();

        Employee()
        {
            name = new char[50];
            id=0;
            strcpy(this->name , "no name");
            pNext = NULL;
            pPrevious =NULL;
        }
        Employee(int id , char* name)
        {
            this->id = id;
            strcpy(this->name , name);
        }

        Employee(Employee &z)
        {
            this->id = z.id;
            strcpy(this->name , z.name);
            //this->name = z.name;
        }
        void operator =(Employee &z)
        {

            this->id = z.id;
            this->name=z.name;
        }
        void operator = (Employee e);


};
```

this is class LinkedList

```
class LinkedList
{
    protected:
        Employee *pStart;
        Employee *pEnd;

    public:
        LinkedList()
        {
            pStart = pEnd = NULL;
            cout<<"constructor is called"<<endl;
        }
        ~LinkedList()
        {
            // freeList();
        }
        void addList(Employee *pltem);
        void insertList(Employee *pltem);
        Employee* searchList(int id);
        int DeleteList(int id);
        void freeList();
        void displayAll();




        //void print();
        int getCounter();
        void insert();
        void Sort();
        void swap(Employee *x , Employee *y);
};
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Use merge sort algorithm. It is applicable and the best for sorting both single and doubly linked list.

Comment: Better to use `std::list` and then call `std::list::sort`.  Also that `Employee` assignment operator looks strange, as it doesn't copy the contents of the `name` buffer into a new buffer.

Comment: i am not using this operator function i assign all data in swap function the problem is this function is not doing what i want@PaulMcKenzie

Comment: Your `sort` function doesn't do anything except attempt go through the list  **one time** and swap out-of-place items (note the word *attempt*) -- even if you swapped items once, that is not going to sort a linked list, or any other data structure (arrays, vectors, etc.) going only once through the data.  Maybe you should review basic sorting algorithms first.  Even start with a naive bubble sort.

Comment: i want at least two swap two nodes i know this will not sort the whole list but first i want to swap two objects and i think this function should swap elements @PaulMcKenzie